# Prevent Rending of name="" in HtmlInputButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

How do I prevent the `name="..."` attribute from rendering as part of an HtmlInputButton?

Code:

```
 var button = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton();
 button.Value = "abc";
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$AppName_Content$ctl01" type="button" value="abc"/>
```

Comment: This may help you: [`How to remove 'name' attribute`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4424499/1042848)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. 
public override void WriteAttribute(string name, string value, bool fEncode)
        {
            if (name == "name) return;
            base.WriteAttribute(name, value, fEncode);
        }

Comment: Glad it helped.!! I just added it as an answer so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the render method and prevent the attribute from being added.

```
private class RemoveNamesHtmlTextWriter : HtmlTextWriter
{    
    public override void WriteAttribute(string name, string value, bool fEncode) 
    { 
        if (name.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return;
            return; 

        base.WriteAttribute(name, value, fEncode); 
    }
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var RemoveNamesWriter = new RemoveNamesHtmlTextWriter(writer);

    base.Render(RemoveNamesWriter);
}
```

You can refer here for more information: [How to remove 'name' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424499/1042848)