# How to set the name attribute of an element in ASP.NET which is not equal to its ID attribute

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a code which I have to use `HTML` elements instead of `ASP.NET` elements. So because I want to have access to the elements from CodeBehind I've set all of their attributes to `runat=server`.

As you know `ASP.NET` changes the `name` attribute of elements to something like `CT100$MainContent$IDNameOfThatElement`. How can I prevent `ASP.NET` to change it? Cuz I have to have some other names because of JQuery stuff...

For example `ASP.NET` changes the `name` attribute from `required` to `CT100$MainContent$PaymentCode` in the following code:

```
<div class="field">
   <input type="text" runat="server" name="required" id="PaymentCode" />
</div>
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add **ClientIDMode="Static"**

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can't override the name attribute without jumping through some hoops. What you can do is create a controlAdapter that can control which attributes will be rendered and how.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424476/how-to-remove-name-attribute-from-server-controls) answer for an idea about how to accomplish your goal.